# jQuery events propagated from SVG elements in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, raphael

Is there a good way to get around IE7 producing "Error: Failed" when events are triggered on dynamically created SVG elements (such as those created by raphael.js)?

I think the "Error: Failed" are being produced when jQuery looks through my live handlers to check and see if the SVG element matches any of the live selectors I've specified... for now I manually bind functions that call

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

for every event (mouseenter, mouseleave, click, etc.) on my SVGs produced by raphael.

Comment: IE 7 supports SVG? Raphael.js uses VML for IE if i recall correctly.

Comment: Ahh. Ok -- I'm having trouble with the events triggered by the VML drawings then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a good way to prevent this jQuery issue.

So what I ened up doing was capturing the events in Raphael.js and calling e.stopPropagation(); then I used IE's fireEvent to start the event again on the parent element of the VML/SVG element. A bit of a hack, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using Brandon Aaron's "livequery" plugin in place of jQuery's native "live" method for any live bindings to the "change" event solved this problem.

See:

[hakoniemi](http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/when-jquery-returns-failed-in-ie-and-how-its-probably-resolved/)

[jQuery Bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7071)